# i am beginner in ,net programming.i am starting to connect with weigh scale and get scale digit in my textbox

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

When i execute my code it works properly when weight is change.But problem is that my text box shows 01B  etc.please help me to get what wrong in code.i want it as int in human readable format like 0546 etc.

```
if (InvokeRequired)     //<-- Makes sure the function is invoked to work properly in the UI-Thread
    BeginInvoke(new Closure(() => { SerialPortOnDataReceived(sender, serialDataReceivedEventArgs); }));     //<-- Function invokes itself
else
{
    while (_serialPort.BytesToRead > 0) //<-- repeats until the In-Buffer is empty
    {
        int dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
        byte[] data = new byte[dataLength];
        int nbrDataRead = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
        if (nbrDataRead == 0)
            return;
        string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
        textBox1.Text = str.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: 04C, 03N ,03D, 04F, what is this, hex? because is the real string value of your buffer

Comment: 003 is hex value :/

Comment: you need to check which format you need and transform the value, you don't tell us the format type you need

Comment: ofcourse i need int format 0030kg etc

Comment: and i just want to know that why textbox show  
04C, 03N ,03D, 04F instead of numeric weight :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your hexadecimal fetched weight in decimal:

```
 string str = GetValidNumber(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data));
 int dec = int.Parse(str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
 textBox1.Text = dec.ToString() + "kg";
```

You need to check for valid ascii chars in your string so you can use this methods:

```
 public string GetValidNumber(String numberToValid)
    {
        string validNumber = "";
        bool isValidChar = false;

        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < numberToValid.Length; i++)
            {
                isValidChar = CheckAsciiChar(numberToValid[i].ToString());

                if (isValidChar)
                    validNumber += numberToValid[i];
            }
            return validNumber;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}            
    }

    private bool CheckAsciiChar(string c)
    {
        bool isValid = false;
        try
        {
            byte[] asciiBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(c);

            for (int i = 48; i <= 57; i++)
            {
                if (asciiBytes[0] == i)
                    isValid = true;
            }

            for (int i = 65; i <= 90; i++)
            {
                if (asciiBytes[0] == i)
                    isValid = true;
            }

            for (int i = 97; i <= 122; i++)
            {
                if (asciiBytes[0] == i)
                    isValid = true;
            }

            if (asciiBytes[0] == 250)
                isValid = true;

            return isValid;
        }
        catch (Exception ex){}            
    }
```

Comment: Its show exception message input string was not in correct format

Comment: in which lane??

Comment: int dec = int.Parse(str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); in this line

Comment: can you tell me `str` value?

Comment: this is the out put value of string in textbox 01Bkg

Comment: check that two methods and try it again